# Wrong output with 0 bricks pyramid building python

Tags: python

I'm making a small script that builds a pyramid out of the users input number, it then outputs the maximum height it can go to.

```
 for n in range(bricks):
     if (n*n)/2 <= bricks:
         height = n+1
     print("The height of the pyramid is:", height)
```

When I put "0" in it still puts height of "1", I get that's because of the +1 but without that there it will give a syntax error, and will also display the wrong height when putting just "1" brick in, any ideas on how to fix this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may desindent the print, it may run at the end of the loop

```
bricks= 0
height = 0
for n in range(bricks):
    if (n*n)/2 <= bricks:
        height = n+1
print("The height of the pyramid is:", height)
```

---

If you extract a method, you'll have

```
def get_height(bricks):
    height = 0
    for n in range(bricks):
        if (n * n) / 2 <= bricks:
            height = n + 1
    return height

for b in range(10):
    print("The height of the pyramid is:", get_height(b), 'for nb_bricks=', b)
```

```
The height of the pyramid is: 0 for nb_bricks= 0
The height of the pyramid is: 1 for nb_bricks= 1
The height of the pyramid is: 2 for nb_bricks= 2
The height of the pyramid is: 3 for nb_bricks= 3
The height of the pyramid is: 3 for nb_bricks= 4
The height of the pyramid is: 4 for nb_bricks= 5
The height of the pyramid is: 4 for nb_bricks= 6
The height of the pyramid is: 4 for nb_bricks= 7
The height of the pyramid is: 5 for nb_bricks= 8
The height of the pyramid is: 5 for nb_bricks= 9
```